# Is it possible to call getevent from an Android service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions

Is is possible to run getevent from an Android service and get output similar to what you see when running adb to call getevent from a command prompt on a development machine?  When I try something like:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder()
    .command("getevent")
    .redirectErrorStream(true)
    .start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(builder.getInputStream()));
...
```

the output I get for each device looks like:

could not open /dev/input/event[n], Permission denied

Is it just not possible to access low level information like this because of Android's security protections?  Would it be possible on a "rooted" device?

Why I am trying to do this:
I would like to record a user's actions (touch and gesture events) on an Android device for the purpose of usability testing.  An accessibility service seems to be the way to go, but the information is not detailed enough.  For a swipe gesture, for example, I cannot get the screen coordinates of where the user swiped.  I was thinking that getting the low-level input from the touch screen might let me get more detailed information.  Maybe there is a better way to do this?
(I'm a newbie in the Android world.  This kind of thing is easy on Windows.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this.

```
th = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        private Process exec;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","getevent -t " + device});
                InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(
                        exec.getInputStream());
                String s;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
                while(((s = br.readLine()) != null) && run){
                    ...
                }
                is.close();
                exec.destroy();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
}
```

You must use **'su' to get the root permission**, but by this way you can't get the **real time** event, because there is **a buffer size of 4k**, you could get data only after contained 4k data.

Answer (score 1):

Your phone must be **rooted** to execute getevent/sendevent command.

One way is to install any terminal emulator from play store like  [Qute: Command Console & Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ddm.qute&hl=en).

In terminal enter following:

1) `su` (it'll gain the root access required for `getevent`)

2)  `getevent` (or `getevent -c 8` to output only 8 lines else it would flood the terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Search for UIAutomator. This does what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Termux app as your terminal emulator, you can click `CTRL` (in the command bar above the keyboard) then `c` on the keyboard to exit from the `getinput` command (or any other command that continues to spew data to stdout (the screen)).